# Using Apply to convert numeric columns to factors with labels

Tags: r, apply

I have a likert Scale of 5 items with five possible where i am trying to visualize it using the package `likert`. The final aim is to have a chart for each construct showing how the users answered somehow using a facet. The package requires that everything be a factor which i have done using the following code per column

```
myscale$scale_1 <- factor (myscale$scale_1, 
                        levels = c(0:5),
                        labels=c("Unanswered","1","2","3","4","5"))
```

I thought this would be an excellent way to use lapply to apply this to all five columns in the dataframe. I have attempted it below but am kind of hitting a wall. I have seen some examples

```
lapply(myscale,factor(levels = c(0:5), labels=c("Unanswered","1","2","3","4","5")))
```

Comment: Hi @RHertel, Thank you for the quick response. The first batch of code works but i don't want to end up doing this for each scale. So that code is for `scale_1` but i have `scale_1` to `Scale_5` for 15 constructs so i was hoping to generalize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are using `lapply` without an anonymous function call, the arguments of the new function can be passed as such.

```
myscale[] <- lapply(myscale, factor, levels = 0:5, 
                    labels = c("Unanswered", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

If we use anonymous function call,

```
myscale[] <- lapply(myscale, function(x) factor(x, levels = 0:5,
                labels =c("Unanswered", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

---

The above can be also done with `mutate_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
myscale %<>% 
   mutate_each(funs(factor(., levels = 0:5, labels = c("Unanswered", 1:5))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
myscale <- data.frame(scale_1 = sample(0:5, 20, replace=TRUE),
           scale_2 = sample(0:5, 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this was really helpful. Just for my own knowledge why do you have the square brackets after `myscale[]`

Comment: @JohnSmith  The output from `lapply` is a `list`.  By assigning to `myscale` with `[]`, the new output gets the same structure as that of the original myscale but with new vales.